# sed replace and keep double quotes

Tags: regex, sed

I just want to change the server and IP information inside double quotes.

For Example:
original line:

```
"server":"10.10.10.10:3306"
```

OR

```
"server":"localhost:3306"
```

output line:

```
"server":"20.20.20.20:3306"
```

I tried using...

```
sed -i s/.*/\"server\"\:\"20\.20\.20\.20\:3306\"/
```

output:

```
server:20.20.20.20:3306
```

where all double quoest gone? 
it replaces the values but does not keep double quotes. I want it should not change double quotes.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the sed pattern within single quotes. If you do like that, then you don't need to escape the double quotes.

```
$ echo '"server":"10.10.10.10:3306"' | sed 's/.*/"server":"20.20.20.20:3306"/'
"server":"20.20.20.20:3306"
```

**OR**

You could simply do like this,

```
$ echo '"server":"10.10.10.10:3306"' | sed 's/[^":]\+:/20.20.20.20:/'
"server":"20.20.20.20:3306"
$ echo '"server":"localhost:3306"' | sed 's/[^":]\+:/20.20.20.20:/'
"server":"20.20.20.20:3306"
```